# What's a sorched-earth way to block porn from my computer?

Tags: macos, router, dns

This is kind of embarrassing, but I'm looking for a way to block porn/adult content sites on a Mac that can't be easily undone.

I've using https://selfcontrolapp.com/ and it's been great (after a site is blocked you can't do anything about it until the timer is done), but unfortunately it can only block sites I've specified beforehand, and I'm looking for a more blanketed solution.

Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: As long as you are an admin on the computer, you can always remove any restrictions. So, for the really embarrassing part: you'd have to ask someone else to set up these restrictions for you and not give you admin access. That, or self-restraint.

Answer (score 1):

There is no singular answer but you can enable parental controls, install extensions to your browser that have very strict filters, and my opinionated best answer for a blanket block: Set your DNS to a safe server like OpenDNS Family IPs (done via your network connection settings) so you will be redirected/blocked from looking up any IP in their database. But even then, if you're smart enough to set this bandaid up, you can just as easily tear it off. How about VPNs, or finding posts on social networks you don't want DNS to block like Reddit? I guess find a DNS that blocks it ALL.

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[5 Porn Blockers to Block Porn on Mac and How to Use Them](https://www.cisdem.com/resource/block-porn-mac.html).

It lists these methods :

- Use [Cisdem AppCrypt](https://www.cisdem.com/appcrypt-mac.html)
- Use [Apple’s Screen Time](https://www.cisdem.com/resource/apple-screen-time-not-working.html)
- Use Parental Controls
- Use the BlockSites browser extension
- Use URL Filtering on the router

You could try one or more of these methods, which seem not to be
contradictory. Using more than one will require more determination
and make it more complicated to undo any protection that you have put
in place.